# Sending JSON to server is giving 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: java, json, angularjs, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I have the following angular code:

```
<button ng-click="ctrl.submit(light)">Switch</button>
```

and the button click is handled by:

```
   self.submit = function(light) {
        console.log("==============================");
        console.log("clicked button: ", light);
        console.log("==============================");

        $http.post('/ARHomeAutomation/rest/light/state/', light).then(function(response) {
            console.log('headers: ' , response.headers);
            console.log('status: ', response.status);
            console.log('config: ', response.config);
            console.log('data: ', response.data);
            self.state = response.data;
        }, function(errResponse) {
          console.error('Error while updating light state');
        })
        console.log('User clicked submit with: ', light.id );
        console.log('response: ', self.light);
    }
```

On the server side I have the following method that should respond to the request:

```
 @POST
 @Path("/state/")
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
 public String setStateOfLight(JSONObject aLight) {
    if(aLight == null) {
      return "It's a null";
    } else {
      System.out.println("content: " + aLight);
    }
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    //Update the state of the light with the given id
    for(Light light: lightCollection) {
        // .....
    }
    return getLightsStateAsJSON();
 }
```

When I click my button I get the following message:

[image: 415 Unsupported MediaType]

According to firefox I do send JSON in my request. At least it says so when I examine the send data.

[image: Showing JSON data]

This is my header request data:

[image: Header content]

What am I missing here?

Comment: Possible you don't have a `MessageBodyReader` for the type `JSONObject`. I would imagine this is logged in the server if this is the case

Comment: peeskillet, There is no logging on the server side. As if it never gets there in the first place.

Comment: What JAX-RS implementation (and version) are you using?

Comment: Or can you just show all your dependencies Maven or just jars.

Comment: You want to know this:      Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1407413291581
Build-Id: 08/07/2014 02:08 PM
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_60
Built-By: m_potociar
Bundle-Description: Java API for RESTful Web Services (JAX-RS)
Bundle-DocURL: http://www.oracle.com/
Bundle-License: http://glassfish.java.net/public/CDDL+GPL_1_1.html, http
 ://glassfish.java.net/public/CDDL+GPL_1_1.html
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: javax.ws.rs-api
Bundle-SymbolicName: javax.ws.rs-api
Bundle-Vendor: Oracle Corporation
Bundle-Version: 2.0.1

That did not print as I wanted it...

Comment: No. You see all the annotations you are using. `@Path`, etc, those are JAX-RS annotations. JAX-RS is a specification. It is not possible to run a JAX-RS application without an implementation. An implementation can be Jersey, CXF, etc. I would like to know which one you are using, and if you can post all your jar dependencies along with that information. I'm thinking you are simply missing some jars and configuration

Comment: Also as a test, can you simply accept a String, instead of `JSONObject` in the method signature, and see what happens. My guess is simply there is no reader for the `JSONObject`

Comment: I tried your service. I've modified a little.
Instead this `public String setStateOfLight(JSONObject aLight) ` I used my bean class `public String setStateOfLight(Light aLight) ` and it worked.

Comment: I downloaded Jersey 2.17 with all dependencies. AT least that what it says on their download site. I will try the String thing later on. My course is starting now.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "I downloaded Jersey 2.17 with all dependencies. AT least that what it says on their download site"

Yeah so [the Jersey distribution (Jersey JAX-RS 2.0 RI bundle )](https://jersey.java.net/download.html) doesn't come bundled with an JSON conversion support, besides basic low level types, that can be converted from an `InputStream`. So without anything else beside the jars that come in that Jersey Bundle, the only type you have use are `String`, `InputStream` and `byte[]`. Doesn't really help much if you are trying to manipulate the JSON

How conversion works is through the use of `MessageBodyReader`s and `MessageBodyWriter`s. I don't know what `JSONObject` is, but I'm guessing it's from [here](http://www.json.org/java/). In any case, you will need a `MessageBodyReader` for it to handle the incoming conversion. My guess is you don't have one. I personally don't know where to get one for that specific API.

I would instead make use of a library that can handle JSON to POJO mapping. Jackson is the one I would recommend. The basic are pretty easy to understand. Say this is your JSON

```
{"name":"your name", "id": "2"}
```

All you need to do is create a class with fields an properties, using [JavaBean naming convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans). So for the above JSON, we could use this

```
public class User {
    private String name;
    private String id;

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public String getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(String id) { this.id = id; }
}
```

Now your method parameter can accept a `User` type.

To get this support, you need to add the Jackson provider. Download the below

- [jersey-media-json-jackson](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-json-jackson/2.17)
- Get all the one from the below image

  [image]

  I had an image from another post with v2.2.3- disregard the version. The version you want to get 2.3.2 for all of them. They can all be found at the above link, for the first dependency. Just search for them in the search bar. When you find it, select the version and download it.

After adding these jars. you should have JSON to POJO support.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the header content-type is set to text/html, even though the body is JSON. I imagine you will need to set the content-type to application/json somewhere in the post in the Angular code.

Comment: The response header content type is set to text/html. Not the request header content type. Or, another possibility, I do not understand the meaning of Response and request headers.